# CSS Grid - autofill on specified number of columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using grid and I want a layout with 3 columns. I can do this by setting:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr)
```

However, when I resize the browser, it will stay as 3 columns. I want it that if the screen size is smaller, it will also adjust the number of columns (responsive). I found this to solve that problem:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(350px,1fr))
```

But the problem here is that I have 1 div that spans 2 columns (grid-column: 2/4). Thus, the 2nd solution doesn't work anymore. And, I want that 2-column div to scale base on screen size also.

Basically, I want the result to be like this:
[image]

Is this even possible with CSS grid?

Comment: Or use media queries, that's what they are for.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, yeah typo. I meant auto-fill.

Comment: @Paulie_D media query was my last resort. I was hoping there's a syntax in css grid to achieve this. I've used up all what I can think of, so yeah, I think I have to use media query for this.

Comment: Are you using plain css? or can you use sass? Because there may be something to do with sass that simplifies what you want

Comment: I'm using vanilla css